# How can I compare two same PostgreSQL tables for equality of the data at row level?

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to compare two same PostgreSQL tables to check if they are equals in rows data, so if they are not equals I want to see the different rows. How can I do that automatically? Is there any library or a tool for that?

(I need to check that with Java language but if you know other ways please share)

Comment: Do the tables have identical primary keys and different data, or different primary keys and the same data?

Comment: There can be different data with same primary key, so comparing with primaries are not true in my problem.

Comment: Can either table be missing IDs?

Comment: @Bohemian, no ids are primary

Comment: @prenses_mahmut that's not what I meant: I am asking if both tables have exactly the same ids for their rows, so that no table has an id that the other table does not.

Answer (score 0):

What about pure SQL? You can translate it into JDBC then

From [this website](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/compare-two-tables-in-postgresql/)

```
SELECT
    ID,
    NAME,
    'not in bar' AS note
FROM
    foo
EXCEPT
    SELECT
        ID,
        NAME,
        'not in bar' AS note
    FROM
        bar
```

OR this

```
SELECT
    id,
    name
FROM
    foo
FULL OUTER JOIN bar USING (id, name)
WHERE
    foo.id IS NULL
OR bar.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you have the same primary key but may have different data.
Lets consider two tables `customer` and `customer_backup` with the following schema:

```
create table customer (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
    insert into customer (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'John', 'Doe');
    insert into customer (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'Test', 'Test');
    insert into customer (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'Jack', 'Smith');
    
create table customer_backup (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
    insert into customer_backup (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'John', 'Doe');
    insert into customer_backup (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'Test', 'Jack');
    insert into customer_backup (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'Will', 'Smith');
```

So to find the diffrences you could specify in the `where` clause all the fields from the first table, that must not be equal to all the fields from the second table:

```
select *
from customer c
         join customer_backup b on c.id = b.id
where c.firstname <> b.firstname
   or c.lastname <> b.lastname
 # or c.otherField <> (not equal) b.otherField
```

You can check this [working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3076d4/6).

Comment: You can actually simplify the WHERE condition to `where c is distinct from b` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7cb3ef0122d8e5dedf8c66c1abc3552b - but you probably want a full join rather than a join